# Need to use asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I want to use ASP.net mvc3.I have VS 2010 installed and my OS is Windows XP SP3. Someone please suggest me what all things i need to install. so to run my application on VS 2010 and do i need to install Visual web developer 2010 express. Is it more useful than VS 2010.
Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have VS2010 installed you don't need VS2010 Express. The Express version is a free lightweight version of Visual Studio. So in your case all you need to do is to install the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491) (`AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe`).

Comment: thank a ton. Please clarify one more thing. how visual  studio 2010 and visual web developer are different?

Comment: Visual Studio Web Developer is the express edition. It allows you to create only web applications. You cannot create for example desktop applications with it.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate answer.